# Clear the OutputCache of a web service WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, webmethod

I have a web service containing a method which is cached using `CacheDuration`:

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 300)]
public bool CacheTest()
{
    return true;
}
```

Which is in turn called in an ASP.NET MVC project:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    var cacheResult = _testWebService.Test();
    return Ok(cacheResult.ToString());
}
```

I want to be able to clear the cache for `CacheTest`, either from within my web service or the ASP.NET MVC project.

I've looked into using `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem`, however, that only seems to clear the cache for the `Test` controller method and not the `CacheTest` web service  method.

I've also tried using `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove()`, but I do not have a key for the `CacheTest` cache.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to clear the cache?

Comment: @mjwills From another method within either project. The browser is not caching the result, the server where the web service is located is.

Comment: How does the other method within either project decide that the cache should be cleared?

Comment: @mjwills It doesn't decide, it would be a call at the end of the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to reduce the `CacheDuration` for `CacheTest` (say to 10 seconds). Then change `CacheTest` to use a `MemoryCache` internally, with the cache duration there set to 300 (as it is now).

When you want to remove an item from the cache, remove it from the `MemoryCache`. Then, within 10 seconds (or whatever you set the `CacheDuration` to) your web service will reflect any recent changes.

Comment: Would `MemoryCache` be able to handle if `CacheTest` used parameters?

Comment: Yes, you'd use those parameters as part of the key.

Comment: I happened to solve this using a different method, but only due to a requirement which came through regarding multi threading. This answers the question though and worked when I first implemented it, so thank you!